# Linking Openvibe to Ros Noetic using vrpn_client_ros

Tags: ros-noetic

I’m working on a project linking Openvibe 3.5.0 with ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 using the vrpn_client_ros package however I’m running into some issues.

When I run the vrpn_client_ros using the sample.launch it creates the trackers for the senders from the openvibe-example-openvibe-to-vrpn VRPN tutorial however doesn’t create any topics?

I’ve pasted the output of the sample.launch below, I’m still fairly new to Ubuntu and ROS so any advice would be greatly appreciated!
SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

```
/rosdistro: noetic
/rosversion: 1.16.0
/vrpn_client_node/broadcast_tf: True
/vrpn_client_node/frame_id: world
/vrpn_client_node/port: 3883
/vrpn_client_node/refresh_tracker_frequency: 1.0
/vrpn_client_node/server: localhost
/vrpn_client_node/update_frequency: 100.0
/vrpn_client_node/use_server_time: False
```

NODES
/
vrpn_client_node (vrpn_client_ros/vrpn_client_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[vrpn_client_node-1]: started with pid [25088]
[ INFO] [1693486354.049358745]: Connecting to VRPN server at localhost:3883
check_vrpn_cookie(): VRPN Note: minor version number doesn’t match: (prefer ‘vrpn: ver. 07.34’, got ‘vrpn: ver. 07.31 0’). This is not normally a problem.
[ INFO] [1693486354.074074495]: Connection established
[ INFO] [1693486355.075989995]: Found new sender: openvibe_vrpn_analog
[ INFO] [1693486355.076091056]: Creating new tracker openvibe_vrpn_analog
[ INFO] [1693486355.077776328]: Found new sender: openvibe_vrpn_button
[ INFO] [1693486355.077815300]: Creating new tracker openvibe_vrpn_button